# How to read sqoop options in PutTransformer class

Tags: sqoop

we have implemented PutTransformer class for our use case. We want to use bucketting concept in ROW KEY ID, so we want to pass the number of Buckets from out side which we will be configured in a config file. Is it possible to read sqoop options in PutTransformer class.

I am passing customized sqoop put transformer class using the option "sqoop.hbase.insert.put.transformer.class".

Any idea on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PutTransformer](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hbase/PutTransformer.java) class is currently not exposing Hadoop's configuration object. I would suggest to file a new feature request on [Sqoop JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP) to add such capability!